# Function to generate two random numbers between 0 and 1 as a pair of [x y]

Tags: function, random, clojure

Haven’t used clojure in a while would appreciate some help

I tried doing

```clj
(defn num [] (rand-int 2) (rand-int 2))
```

Comment: i would say you need `(repeatedly 2 #(rand-int 2))`

Answer (score 3):

```clj
(defn randints [] [(rand-int 2) (rand-int 2)])
```

if you meant random integers between 0 and 1.  Or

```clj
(defn randfloats [] [(rand) (rand)])
```

if you meant random floating point numbers between 0 and 1.